# Magento2 : Change the number of an existing invoice

Tags: magento2, database, orders, invoice, magento2.3

We moved from a different shop sytem to Magento 2.3 and customers already made some orders (Yay!). Due to some regulations all invoice numbers must be continuous.

**How can I change the number of an already existing invoice?**

Currently the latest invoice in Magento has the number *"000000012"* and I'd like to change it to *"000004108"* (for example) since the latest invoice was *"000004107"* in the old system.

I already found out about the table **sequence_invoice_1** which I can modify to set the correct value for the next orders. Modifying existing values in this table did not affect exiting invoices. I suspect there must be some modifications done in the tables **sales_invoice** or **sales_invoice_grid**.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to update the rows in `sales_invoice` and corresponding in `sales_invoice_grid` and change the `increment_id`. With that changes you're done.

Comment: Here is what I did: In the table **sequence_invoice_1** I changed the value from *12* to *4107* and set the table's *AUTO_INCREMENT* to *4018* so the next invoice gets the correct number. In the tables **sales_invoice** and **sales_invoice_grid** I changed the values of the column *increment_id* from *000000012* to *000004107*. Everything works!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two scenarios.

**1) Multi-store environment.**

if you got a multi-store setup with your Magento 2 then you have to check for which store you would like to increase an id.

Don't make any changes via the update but all you need to do is via alter database command, so you have to alter the auto_increment id.

For **order Id update**

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Here sequence_order_1 is the table and it's going to save all order id sequence for the store id 1. you may have multiple stores so you have to figure that out and based on that you can make amends here. The alter table command let you update the auto-increment field value for this sequence table so next order it will start with 100,

For **invoice Id update**

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Here sequence_invoice_1 is the table and it's going to save all invoice id sequence for the store id 1. you may have multiple stores so you have to figure that out and based on that you can make amends here. The alter table command let you update the auto-increment field value for this sequence table so next invoice it will start with 100,

**2) stand-alone environment.**

The majority of the shop is a stand-alone ( default store ) setup with Magento. you can be logged into the database and check the default store id for **sequence_order_...** and **sequence_invoice_...**

Here ... means your store id.

After the above findings, you have to run the following command based on your requirements.

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_... AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_... AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Don't forget to ... with your store id and you don't need to change any other tables or anything at all.

I hope this would help you with your task.

Regards,Sam